# Secret masking with Cypress recordings

Tags: cypress

I couldn't find a similar question here. We have been piloting Cypress for our E2E tests. One thing that is not overtly obvious but feels problematic is the fact that in the videos that are being recorded by Cypress, any secret texts (passwords) that are being typed in are being logged in the video recording. Have folks run into this issue before? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: May I ask why the videos need to show to others? A test report and screenshots are not sufficient? If not you can turn off the video option.

Comment: Even screenshots, when it fails on that step/screen is going to have that problem. Not really "showing" videos to others, but when tests run on CI and artifacts are auto-uploaded, there will be little control over who sees it (though CI is internal, this is not ideal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your webpage itself is not showing cleartext. There is a way to hide from cypress commands.

Add

```
cy.get('yourelement').type('password',{log:false});
```

Then you can see the command is hidden.

[image]

see [cypress doc.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Arguments)